# Pagination with JSP servlet and Bootstrap

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, servlets, pagination

I have the following coding of a data table in JSP. it gives results taken from a servlet and post in the table. I need a pagination for the results.

```
<table class="table table-striped hero-spacer">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Index Number</b></td>
                        <td><b>First Name</b></td>
                        <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
                        <td><b>Date of Birth</b></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <%
                    int count = 0;
                    String style = "";
                    if (request.getAttribute("piList") != null) {
                        ArrayList al = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("piList");
                        System.out.println(al);
                        Iterator itr = al.iterator();
                        while (itr.hasNext()) {

                            if ((count % 2) == 0) {
                                style = "info";
                            }
                            count++;
                            ArrayList pList = (ArrayList) itr.next();
                %>

                <tbody>
                    <tr class="<%=style%>">
                        <td><%=pList.get(0)%></td>
                        <td><%=pList.get(1)%></td>
                        <td><%=pList.get(2)%></td>
                        <td><%=pList.get(3)%></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <%
                    }
                    }
                    if (count == 0) {
                %>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="warning">
                        <td colspan="4 text-center"><b>No Record Found..</b></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </table>
```

Comment: This might help :https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Answer (score -1):

Here is the example for pagination of boostrap.

Html example in here add class correctly.

```
 <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Airi Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>2008/11/28</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2012/12/02</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>2012/08/06</td>
                    <td>$137,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>55</td>
                    <td>2010/10/14</td>
                    <td>$327,900</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>39</td>
                    <td>2009/09/15</td>
                    <td>$205,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>2008/12/13</td>
                    <td>$103,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2008/12/19</td>
                    <td>$90,560</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2013/03/03</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>36</td>
                    <td>2008/10/16</td>
                    <td>$470,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                    <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>2012/12/18</td>
                    <td>$313,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>2010/03/17</td>
                    <td>$385,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michael Silva</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2012/11/27</td>
                    <td>$198,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                    <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2010/06/09</td>
                    <td>$725,000</td>
                </tr>
    </table>
```

Java Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

Comment: What kind of answer is that? Question is about how o implement pagination using Bootstrap in JSP but the answer is taking us to North Pole. How do you implement it using JSP hasn't been answered.